# Position of 'much' in a sentence

Tags: grammar

Why do you care about him so much?
Why do you care about so much of him?

Are these sentence correct and their meanings are the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Are these sentences correct and are their meanings the same?*

The first one is fine. *So much* describes the degree of care.

The second one is odd, because *so much* describes how large a part of him you care for, which doesn't make sense.